# Boot2Docker on Mac - Returns bsdthread_register error

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, docker

I have just installed Boot2Docker 1.2.0 on Mac OSX 10.9.4. When I run any boot2docker command, I get this error:

```
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x522c75)
    /usr/src/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:520 +0x69
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/src/go/src/pkg/runtime/os_darwin.c:88 +0x62
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/src/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:164 +0x76
_rt0_go()
    /usr/src/go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:91 +0x114
```

I also tried using Boot2Docker 1.1.2 with the same problem. Can somebody give me a pointer on where to look?

Thanks,
Suriyanto

Answer (score 1):

If running boot2docker from the command line try issuing this command first:

```
unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
```

Sometimes other programs that have been installed on the system inject themselves into other programs dynamically causing errors like this. `unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` prevent insertion of such dynamic objects from being added to a program at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I did the first time I got this error according to https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/397. It didn't make a difference and I still get the error.

Comment: As an experiment what happens if you create a new user account on OS/X and try running it as another user?

Comment: Sorry but tried that as well. I have also realized that when I just simply issue docker, I get the same error.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at this point would be to consider building Boot2Docker rather than installing a pre-made binary.

Comment: I fixed this issue by building it through Brew. Not ideal as I don't like the idea of having it managed by Brew, but it will have to do for now. I will update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After spending half a day on this, I decided to install boot2docker through Homebrew and it works. For steps on installing it through Brew, refer to:

http://blog.javabien.net/2014/03/03/setup-docker-on-osx-the-no-brainer-way/.

Not necessarily the answer, but this will help anybody in the future from getting stucked.